# RETURNING data from updatable view not working?

Tags: postgresql

I have two simple tables `person` and `address` with inserts going through an updatable view `person_details`.

### Relations and trigger

```
CREATE TABLE address (
  id          serial PRIMARY KEY,
  street      varchar,
  town        varchar NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE person (
  id          serial PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name  varchar,
  family_name varchar NOT NULL,
  address     integer REFERENCES address
);
```

The owner obviously has full permissions, but regular users can only access the data through a view which includes details from both tables:

```
CREATE VIEW person_details AS
  SELECT p.id, p.first_name, p.family_name, a.street, a.town
  FROM person p
  LEFT JOIN address a ON a.id = p.address;
```

The view is updatable such that regular users can `INSERT` into the tables underlying the view:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON person_details TO public;
```

I have defined the trigger to propagate the `INSERT` to the tables and all works just fine:

```
CREATE FUNCTION t0ii_person_details() RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
  addr  integer;
BEGIN
  -- Want at least a town to insert anything into table address.
  IF (NEW.town IS NOT NULL) THEN
    INSERT INTO address(street, town)
      VALUES (NEW.street, NEW.town)
      RETURNING id INTO addr;
  ELSE
    addr := NULL;
  END IF;

  INSERT INTO person(first_name, family_name, address)
    VALUES (NEW.first_name, NEW.family_name, addr);
  RETURN NEW;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY DEFINER;

CREATE TRIGGER t0ii_person_details
  INSTEAD OF INSERT ON person_details
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE t0ii_person_details();
```

### INSERT - ok

A simple insert:

```
pfams=# INSERT INTO person_details (first_name, family_name, town) VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'Eders');
INSERT 0 1

pfams=# SELECT * FROM person_details;
 id | first_name | family_name | street |  town
----+------------+-------------+--------+--------
  1 | John       | Doe         |        | Eders
(1 row)
```

### INSERT RETURNING id - not ok

However, if I want to return the newly assigned `id` (originating from the `person` table where it is generated from a sequence, `serial` data type) directly from the `INSERT` statement, then I get nothing back:

```
pfams=# INSERT INTO person_details (first_name, family_name, town) VALUES ('Jim', 'Doe', 'Eders') RETURNING id;
 id
----

(1 row)

INSERT 0 1
```

But the data is there:

```
pfams=# SELECT * FROM person_details;
 id | first_name | family_name | street |  town
----+------------+-------------+--------+--------
  1 | John       | Doe         |        | Eders
  2 | Jim        | Doe         |        | Eders
(2 rows)
```

What am I missing here?

```
pfams=# SELECT version();
                                               version
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.3.6 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3, 32-bit
```

Comment: You can try `INSERT INTO person ... RETURNING id INTO NEW.id` inside the trigger, but the docs do not mention `RETURNING` support explicitly with an `INSTEAD OF` trigger. But (if that doesn't work) you can use [`INSTEAD` rules](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createrule.html). The docs explicitly mentions `RETURNING` support: *If you want to support INSERT RETURNING and so on, then be sure to put a suitable RETURNING clause into each of these rules.*

Comment: The docs do also mention explicitly that _in practice triggers are easier to understand and use correctly_, and they do not mention quite a few other possible things explicitly. I do find it a bit odd that the behaviour is different between a regular table and an updatable view; they are both relations returning tuples. But all this ranting aside, your first suggestion works! Do you want to make that an answer?

Comment: This behaviour is quite odd, they way I see it. It means that you have to hard-code in the trigger function what is returned from it. With an insert on a regular table you can return any column. So the only way right now to circumvent this is something like `INSERT ... RETURNING * INTO NEW`. But that obviously does not work with a complex view... Should this be a feature request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were so close ;) you only need to update `NEW.id` in your trigger.

```
CREATE FUNCTION t0ii_person_details() RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
  addr  integer;
BEGIN
  -- Want at least a town to insert anything into table address.
  IF (NEW.town IS NOT NULL) THEN
    INSERT INTO address(street, town)
      VALUES (NEW.street, NEW.town)
      RETURNING id INTO addr;
  ELSE
    addr := NULL;
  END IF;

  INSERT INTO person(first_name, family_name, address)
    VALUES (NEW.first_name, NEW.family_name, addr) 
    -- here is the only change I made
    RETURNING id INTO NEW.id;
  RETURN NEW;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY DEFINER;
```