# PLPGSQL function returning trigger AND value

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, sql-view, sql-returning

I have written a PL/PGSQL function that returns a trigger, so I can call it before each row insert. I realize now that I would also like that function to return the ID of the newly inserted row. I'm not quite sure how to proceed since my function must return a trigger. Here's some code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_insert_album() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
    subj_album_id INTEGER;
BEGIN
    -- ... some parts where left out
    INSERT INTO t_albums_subjective (user_id, album_id, format_id, location_id, rating) 
    VALUES (NEW.user_id, obj_album_id, NEW.format_id, NEW.location_id, NEW.rating) 
    RETURNING id INTO subj_album_id;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- Bind insert function to trigger
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS tr_v_albums_insert ON v_albums; 
CREATE TRIGGER tr_v_albums_insert INSTEAD OF INSERT ON v_albums
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE f_insert_album();
```

I must keep the return type of my function `f_insert_album()` to `TRIGGER`, but I would really like to also return the value in `subj_album_id`, corresponding to the `id` of the newly inserted row.

Is there anyway to do this? Is it even possible? Obviously changing the return type didn't work with Postgres. Could you suggest an alternative approach if any?

Comment: You'd have to store the generated identifier into the tuple that fired the trigger, if there's an appropriate field, and use `INSERT ... RETURNING...` for the top level query too. Or use a notification payload via `LISTEN` and `NOTIFY`.

Comment: Thanks Craig, although I'm not quite sure I understand very well ! Could you please elaborate your first idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crucial question: ***where*** to return the ID to?

Assuming you want to return it from the `INSERT` statement directly, then you are almost there. You already assign the newly generated ID to a function parameter:

```
...
RETURNING id INTO subj_album_id;
```

Instead, assign it to a column of the row firing the trigger. The [special variable **`NEW`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) holds this row in a trigger function:

```
...
RETURNING id INTO NEW.album_id;  -- use actual column name in view
```

Then use the `RETURNING` clause of the `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO v_albums (user_id, format_id, location_id, rating) 
VALUES ( ... ) 
RETURNING album_id;
```

Obviously, this is only possible if there ***is*** a visible column in the view. It does not have to be assigned in the `INSERT` command, though. The type of the `NEW` row variable is defined by the definition of the view, not by the `INSERT` at hand.

Closely related:

- [RETURNING data from updatable view not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30137316/returning-data-from-updatable-view-not-working)

---

For what you *seem* to be doing (grant access to certain rows of a table to a certain role) row level security (**RLS**) in Postgres 9.5 or later might be a more convenient alternative:

- [`CREATE POLICY` in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createpolicy.html)
- [The Postgres Wiki: "What's new in PostgreSQL 9.5"](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.5#Row-Level_Security_Policies)
- [Review by Depesz](https://www.depesz.com/2014/10/02/waiting-for-9-5-row-level-security-policies-rls/)

Comment: Thanks a billion ! This worked, and the closely related question helped a lot.